# How to Combine Two SQL Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I combine the two sql queries into one:

```
strQuery = "select * from UNITHD where driver1medical BETWEEN '1/1/1990' and GETDATE()+29 ORDER BY driver1medical"
objMedicalDriver1.Open strQuery
```

and

```
strQuery = "select * from UNITHD where driver2medical BETWEEN '1/1/1990' and GETDATE()+29 ORDER BY driver1medical"
objMedicalDriver2.Open strQuery
```

I did find alot of examples here at stackoverflow but I just cannot get it to work :-(

Comment: What is the DDL for driver1medical/driver2medical ?

Comment: Do you want where both drivermedicals are within the date range (AND) or where one or the other or both are within the range (OR)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from UNITHD
where ( driver1medical BETWEEN '1/1/1990' and GETDATE()+29 )
   or ( driver2medical BETWEEN '1/1/1990' and GETDATE()+29 )
ORDER BY driver1medical
```

Comment: GETDATE is today. GETDATE + 29 is around a month from now.

Answer (score 1):

That way it should list all resultds combined, remember that to use the UNION operand, you need to replace * for the list of attributes in both queries so that they match (both in number and in domain):

```
select * from UNITHD where driver1medical BETWEEN '1/1/1990' and GETDATE()+29 ORDER BY driver1medical

UNION

select * from UNITHD where driver2medical BETWEEN '1/1/1990' and GETDATE()+29 ORDER BY driver1medical
```

Comment: @Sparafusile you are absolutely right, i didnt really stoped by to see the queries in details and just posted a possible working solution. My bad!